# Is there an non-linear binary operation that's associative?

Tags: cryptography, nonlinear-system, associativity

In cryptography, non-linearty is an important property in symmetric primitives that ensures trivial linear analysis cannot succeed; associativity is a property that is essential in public-key (a.k.a. asymmetric) cryptography that ensures the correctness key exchange and digital signature schemes.

It's a generally true, that most non-linear operations are also non-associative, but if there exists a associative non-linear operation, it would bridge a major gap between practical and ideal public-key cryptography.

Therefore, I'd like to ask: had there been a known associative binary operation the result of which cannot be represented as a non-trivial linear expression of its input.

e.g.

1. (One of those) Disallowed trivial linear expression: $x=f(a,b)=a+b+n$.
2. $x=gcd(a,b)$ can be represented as $x=n \cdot a + m \cdot b$ with $n,m \in Z$, therefore it's excluded.

Comment: $\gcd (m,n)$ for non-zero integers $m,n.$

Comment: What do you mean by linear?  For most sets there is no obvious meaning to the term, but any set can have an associative binary operation on it.

Comment: I'd like some help on my own answer to my own question: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51570/impossibility-of-associative-pseudorandom-permutation

Comment: It's clear from the wild swing in edits that you have no idea what you want, or at any rate no ability to express what you want clearly and unambiguously. Voting to close.

Comment: Are you asking the following question?

*If we consider a field $F$ and think of $F$ as a vector space where the set of scalars is also $F$, does there exist an associative operator $F \times F \rightarrow F$ that fails to be a bilinear form on $F$?*

Comment: Yes, that it, and the vector space and the set of scalars can have any representation.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by a representation of a vector space and a set of scalars?

Comment: @GerryMyerson as in bit-string and serialization. Sorry I can't find the right word at the moment.

Comment: I don't know what the serialization of a vector space means. Maybe you could edit some examples of what you want and what you don't want into the body of your question.

Comment: @GerryMyerson found the right wording this time I suppose. I meant digital encoding when I said serialization, as in ecoding a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be any nonempty set, let $x$ be an element of $X$, define a binary operation by $yz=x$ for all $y$ and all $z$ in $X$. There is no group operation here, since $X$ is not a group (if it has more than one element), there is no scalar multiplication here, and no division, so this must be exactly what you want. If it isn't what you want, that's a sign that you haven't thought your problem through, and haven't found a way to express what you really want from this operation.

EDIT: The question currently reads, "Therefore, I'd like to ask: had there been a known associative binary operation the result of which cannot be represented as a non-trivial linear expression of its input" (though I'm sure it will change a few more times before we're done – in particular, I imagine that by "non-trivial" OP actually means "trivial"). So, here goes:

On the set of real numbers exceeding 1, consider the operation given by $a*b=a^{\log b}$. It is a simple exercise in the properties of the logarithm function to prove that this operation is associative. I know of no interpretation of the adjectives under which this operation would be called either trivial or linear.

Comment: I see that you have added something to the statement of your question, but I think my answer still applies. If $X$ is the set of all real numbers, or all integers, or all naturals, or whatever you mean by "everyday numbers", and I define $yz=17$ for all $y$ and all $z$, then I'm not doing a sequence of additions, subtractions, multiplications, and divisions.

Comment: You've changed it again, now you don't want matrices. Well, my answer doesn't rely on anything to do with matrices.

Comment: I did mean "non-trivial". Adding arbitrary number to get the expected result is "trivial" cheating, where as the result of a gcd operation is by definition a scalar expression of either of its input.

Comment: Is it appropriate to say that there exist a homomorphic mapping from $(R, \cdot)$ to $(R, *)$

Comment: Yes, if $f(x)=e^x$, then $f(x\cdot y)=f(x)*f(y)$.